# How to click last button of a class children in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

A web page has a button class that contains 0 to a few buttons and I want to click the last button in that class by Selenium:

```
try:
    self.browser.execute_script(
        "document.getElementsByClassName('button_class')[-1].click()") #[-1] means last button on class
except Exception:
    return []
```

But it gives an error. [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLgDX.png)
I have tried this too:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button_class').lastChild.click()
```

but to no avail.

Comment: What's the error thrown?

Comment: @SruthiV I added the image of error message.

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like some earlier part of the script get's an `InvalidArgumentException`. That probably has nothing to do with the code you are showing, since the exception you get should've been caught by the except clause.

See if the company_url or something you are scraping earlier in your code is not `None | "" | undefined`, anything like that.